# mysqld.exe has stopped working in xampp windows?

Tags: mysql, xampp

Mysqld.exe has stopped working in xampp windows.
I started my computer while the XAMPP software was running in the background, MySQL will not start!

> 2017-11-20 11:05:36 14f4 InnoDB: Warning: Using
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>   removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>           2017-11-20 11:05:36 5364 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of
>   small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool
>   at least up to 20MB.
>
> ```
> 2017-11-20 11:05:36 5364 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
> 2017-11-20 11:05:36 5364 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
> 2017-11-20 11:05:36 5364 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2017-11-20 11:05:36 5364 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
> 2017-11-20 11:05:36 5364 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
> 2017-11-20 11:05:36 5364 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
> 2017-11-20 11:05:36 5364 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
> 2017-11-20 11:05:36 5364 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2017-11-20 11:05:37 5364 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
> 2017-11-20 11:05:37 5364 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 1835037 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number
> ```
>
> 11035100176 in the ib_logfiles!
>       2017-11-20 11:05:37 14f4  InnoDB: Operating system error number 38 in a file operation.
>       InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
>       InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
>        InnoDB: Operation read to file D:\win32-packages\build\src\storage\xtradb\os\os0file.cc and at line
>   3174
>       2017-11-20 11:05:37 5364 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 238. Cannot continue operation
>       171120 11:05:37 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
>       This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
>       or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
>       or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
>
> ```
> To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
>
> We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
> diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
> something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
>
> Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB
> key_buffer_size=16777216
> read_buffer_size=262144
> max_used_connections=0
> max_threads=1001
> thread_count=0
> It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
> key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787107 K  bytes of memory
> Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x0
> Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
> where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
> terribly wrong...
> mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
> mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
> mysqld.exe!?element_index@Item@@UAEPAV1@I@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?element_index@Item@@UAEPAV1@I@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?element_index@Item@@UAEPAV1@I@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?element_index@Item@@UAEPAV1@I@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?element_index@Item@@UAEPAV1@I@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?element_index@Item@@UAEPAV1@I@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?element_index@Item@@UAEPAV1@I@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?element_index@Item@@UAEPAV1@I@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?element_index@Item@@UAEPAV1@I@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?fix_length_and_dec@subselect_partial_match_engine@@UAEXPAPAVItem_cache@@@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPAVTHD@@@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPAPAD@Z()
> mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAHPAX@Z()
> mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
> kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
> ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
> ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
> The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
> information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I've also come across this problem recently when I was trying to install XAMPP to my computer running Windows 10.

If you read the warnings that is given by the program you can see that it return a lot of errors regarding OS. Given "D:\win32-packages\build\src\storage\xtradb\os\os0file.cc" I'm assuming that your computer has several disks hence it's not C: drive.

You should try installing XAMPP on your C:/ drive along with the Windows system. This solved the problem for me, previously I had it on my E: drive and I was not able to run mysql, but Apache worked fine.

2LDR: INSTALL XAMPP to your C:/ drive along with your OS and return with feedback :)